# Notation for drawing once from a distribution and reusing values

Tags: distributions, random-variable, notation

Is there a succinct way to denote a one-time draw from a distribution? This is essentially what I want to achieve:

```
f(x):
  if first time encountering x,
    v <- uniform(0, 1)
    return v
  else
    use previously drawn v when this particular value of x was encountered
```

Example:

```
f(1) = 0.5 #first time encountering 1, so we draw from U(0, 1)
f(2) = 0.2 #first time encountering 2, so we draw from U(0, 1)
f(1) = 0.5 #reuse previous value of f(1)
```

$f(x) \sim U(0, 1)$ is my guess but it seems wrong since it indicates I'm drawing from the distribution each time.

Comment: It depends on what "use previously drawn v" might mean: it is undefined in your pseudocode.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I've made the edit to my question. I'm reusing the last v from when that particular value of x was last encountered

Comment: You seem to be trying to define a kind of random function.  Would that be a correct interpretation?

Comment: Does random function mean the same thing as a stochastic process? I just did a lookup of what stochastic processes are and they seem really close to what I'm looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!